# i18next translation being displayed as unicode hex character

Tags: javascript, unicode, i18next

I'm using i18next to handle translations in a project I'm working on and I'm finding that when I hand a string to the translation that contains `/`, it is being converted to the unicode hex code `&#x2f;`

I am setting `title` as:

```
const title = '2/Double/Twin/Triple/Quadrupple'
```

The translation is called as follows:

```
{i18n.t('foo', {
  title,
  amount: '$18'
})}
```

And the translation is setup like:

```
{
  "foo": "foo bar {{title}} howdee {{amount}}"
}
```

However the output is:

```
Foo bar 2&#x2F;Double&#x2F;Twin&#x2F;Triple&#x2F;Quadrupple howdee $18
```

How do I ensure that characters are not converted to their hex code equivalents?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By default i18next escapes content to avoid xss attacks based on user input. You can turn off escaping by prepending `-` or provide escape flag.

```
{
  "foo": "foo bar {{- title}} howdee {{amount}}"
}
```

or

```
{i18n.t('foo', {
  title,
  amount: '$18',
  interpolation: { escapeValue: false }
})}
```

https://www.i18next.com/interpolation.html#unescape

Comment: Excellent. I couldn't find this in the documentation. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Four years later, and you just saved me hours of debugging, thanks :)

Comment: this is the updated docs link: https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation